# Shared variable in concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() python

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I want to use parallel to update global variable using module concurrent.futures in python

It turned out that using ThreadPoolExecutor can update my global variable but the CPU did not use all their potential (always at 5-10%), which is so slow

and ProcessPoolExecutor can use all the cores (at 100%) but my global variable can not be updated because they do not share the same global variable

How can I share my global variable using ProcessPoolExecutor in concurrent.futures model. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: That's the major difference between threads and processes: Processes are seperate instances of the same application with own memory space. Everything needed from the main process has to be copied into the new process (some operating systems handle this more efficient than others) or shared (shared memory for example) in some way. In general it is advisable to keep the data transferred from and to the worker processes small and inside the arguments and return values.

Answer (score 9):

Process doesn't seem like thread that using same memory space. So you need some special way to update variables. `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses the `multiprocessing` module, the are two ways for sharing data, Shared memory and Server process. First way using shared memory map, Server process using `Manager` object that like a proxy to holds sharing data. Server process are more flexible, Shared memory more efficient.

Using Server process sharing data like `ThreadPoolExecutor`, just pass arguments to you function.

```
def running_proxy(mval):
    # consider lock if you need
    return mval.value

def start_executor():
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
        mval = manager.Value('b', 1)
        futures = [executor.submit(running_proxy, mval) for _ in range(5)]
        results = [x.result() for x in futures]
        executor.shutdown()
```

But Shared memory way has some difference, you need setting shared variable to global.

```
def running_shared():
    # consider lock if you need
    return sval.value

def set_global(args):
    global sval
    sval = args

def start_executor():
    sval = multiprocessing.Value('b', 1)
    # for 3.7+
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5, initializer=set_global, initargs=(sval,))
    # for ~3.6
    # set_global(sval)
    # executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    futures = [executor.submit(running_shared) for _ in range(5)]
    results = [x.result() for x in futures]
    executor.shutdown()
```

Answer (score -1):

To share the global variable you have to use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or context maganer. The simplest way can be using a list or dictionary to store the results of the `ProcessPoolExecutor`!

```
import concurrent.futures

# Some function
def do_something(arg):
    output = arg*10
    return output

# List to iterate
sample_list = [5, 4, 6, 2, 3]

# Creating a dictionary to store the results
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
     results = {i:executor.submit(do_something, sample_list[i]) for i in range(len(sample_list))}

# The results are stored in "results" dict
# It can be accessed as a normal dict

for key, values in results.items():
    print(values.result())
```

You can also use `map` instead of `submit`. This also ensures that the sequence of the output from the function corresponds to the inputs!

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(do_something, sample_list)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```