# Variable sharing in Multiprocessing with Python? (ProcessPoolExecutor())

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I want to share a variable among multiple processes.

I read this one: [Shared variable in concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299918/shared-variable-in-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor-python) but it didn't really help my code. I am also not an expert in this and just starting since a few weeks (first year student) :)

How is is possible to share the variable *x* among (all) threads as soon as it becomes available? This is what I have so far:

```
import concurrent.futures, time

def share():
    time.sleep(1)
    global x
    x = "hello!"

def printshare():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            print(x)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"printshare {e}")

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:    
        executor.submit(share)
        executor.submit(printshare)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it gives me the error:

```
printshare name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: You should share a value created by a manager with all processes. Perhaps initialise it to `None` until its ready to be given its correct value.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. What type of manager?

Comment: The same manager that is used in one of the answers in the link you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work:

```
def foo(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    x.string = 'hello'


def foo2(x):
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print(x.string)

def main():
    x = Value('i')

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:    
        executor.submit(foo(x))
        executor.submit(foo2(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```